# I'm using elastic search version 6.0.1. I need to rollover the index when it reaches certain count. Is there any java rest api for version 6.0.1?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to rollover the index using the java rest api. But the java rest api doesn't exist for version 6 of ES. Is there any other possibility to roll over the indices using java rest high level client

Comment: Can you please add more details like why you want to rollover using Java API ? Did you check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index-lifecycle-management.html) documentation ?

Comment: I need to limit the size of the index. So I thought of using the rollover when it reaches certain limit. Sorry the actual version is 6.0.1. I need to achieve the index life cycle management in the version 6.0.1 using java api. Is there any other possibilities or options ?

Comment: ES 6.0 is EOL now and as far as i know not available in ES 6 version so will suggest to move to latest version of Elasticsearch where you will get ILM feature which can do this job with just configuration.

Comment: So, shall I know how the multiple indices are managed in the older versions?

Comment: That i am not sure.

Comment: Any idea about using the elastic search curator?

Comment: not sure as i have not worked on 6.x version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To learn more about this community, please read [ask] and its linked resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are still using 6.0 then;

1. you need to urgently upgrade as this is very much [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) and no longer supported
2. you will need to use [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) as ILM is not available until 6.8

Comment: Is there any documentation for using the curator with the java rest api's?